# How do I make messages only read by two users (private messages) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Mongoid

I need messages in MessagesController to be read only by the user who sent the messages and to whom the message was sent, that is, in fact, private messages between two users

I think I need to do it through scope or before_action, maybe for this I need to add an additional field that will store the id of both users?

I will be glad if you help me

**message.rb**

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created

  field :body, type: String
  field :read,  type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false  
  field :is_deleted, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
  field :conversation_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :sender_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :receiver_id, type: BSON::ObjectId

  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'

  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :sender_id, :receiver_id

  index({ conversation_id: 1 }, { name: 'index_messages_on_conversation_id', background: true })
  index({ user_id: 1 }, { name: 'index_messages_on_user_id', background: true })

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y at %l:%M %p")
  end
end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_conversation, only: [:index, :create]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:index]
  
  def index
    @conversation.messages.where(receiver_id: current_user.id, read: false).update_all(read: true)
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params.except(:recipient_ids))
    @message.sender_id = current_user.id
    @message.receiver_id = @conversation.recipient(current_user)
    @message.save!

  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end

  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def correct_user
    redirect_to root_path if @conversation.messages.any_of({sender_id: current_user.id}, {receiver_id: current_user.id}) == current_user._id
  end
end
```

**conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :is_deleted, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
  field :sender_id, type: Integer
  field :receiver_id, type: Integer

  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy


  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :receiver_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, receiver_id) do
    any_of({sender_id: sender_id, receiver_id: receiver_id}, {sender_id: receiver_id, receiver_id: sender_id})
  end


  def recipient(current_user)
    self.sender_id == current_user.id ? self.receiver : self.sender
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided by a simple check if the current user is not the sender and not the receiver of this `@conversation`, then the user is redirected to the root page

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:index]

private

  def correct_user
    redirect_to root_path unless @conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || @conversation.receiver_id == current_user.id
  end
end
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, I updated the answer and added an explanation